# How to check if a value contains characters in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have values such as

B146XYZ,
G638XYZ,
G488xBC

I have to write a bash script where when it sees comma it has to remove the comma and add 7 spaces to it and also if it sees comma and a space or just space(no punctuations) it has to add 7 spaces to make all of them fixed length.

```
if [[  $row = *’,’* ]]
then
first= “${ row%%,*}”
echo “${first }       “
```

I tried but can’t understand how to add conditions for the remaining criteria specially struggling with single value conditions such as G488xBC

Comment: (also, the space after the `=` completely changes the meaning of `First= ...`, and `"` is a distinct character from `“`; how the shell treats them is completely different)

Comment: You can't use curly quotes in scripts (or most other programming languages). Turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Comment: Please [edit] to _fix_ those errors. We need a [mre] that lets us see your problem ourselves. If we don't know if a problem is caused by a typo in the question or is caused by your real code, how can we answer that question?

Comment: What is `$line`?

Comment: Why did you remove the code? How can we help you fix it? We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: Split the input string into words using command and space as the delimiter. Then you don't need to test for the comma, just add spaces to each word.

Comment: `IFS=', ' read -r -a words <<<"$line"; printf '%-7s\n' "${words[@]}"`

Comment: @user2708013, ...mind, I don't know if that's really what you need, but you aren't providing a [mre] that demonstrates expected/desired output paired with input samples, so there's not enough information in this question to really do anything but guess at your intent.

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
sed -E 's/[, ]+/       /g' file
```

Or something like this will print a padded table, so long as no field is longer than 13 characters:

```
awk -F '[,[:space:]]+' \
'{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        printf("%-14s", $i)
    }

    print $NF
}'
```

Or the same thing in pure bash:

```
while IFS=$', \t' read -ra vals; do
    last=$((${#vals[@]} - 1))

    for ((i=0; i<last; i++)); do
        printf "%-14s" "${vals[i]}"
    done

    printf '%s\n' "${vals[last]}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
newrow="${row//,/       }"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    VALUES=`echo $VALUES | sed 's/,/ /g' | xargs`
```

- The sed command will replace the comma with a single space.
- The xargs will consolidate any number of whitespaces into a single space.

With that you now have your values in space separated string instead of comma, separated by unknown number of whitespaces.

From there you can use `for i in $VALUES; do printf "$i\t"; done`

Using the tab character like above will give you aligned output in case your values may be different in length.

But if your values are always same length then you can make it a bit more simple by doing

```
    VALUES=`echo $VALUES | sed 's/,/ /g' | xargs | sed 's/1 space/7 spaces/g'`
    echo $VALUES
```